# Trying to apply keyboard navigation by 'tabbing' through menu

Tags: jquery, focus, keyboard-events, keycode

Very new to applying 'keyboard navigation', starting with the tabbing (keyCode == 9) through this menu .. so far, all $(.menuItem)s show focus on first 'tab' keydown, I'm unable to tab through each li, ul sub-menu .. help?

```
    <div class="navigation-container">
    <ul class="menu" tabindex="0">
      <li class="menuItem" tabindex="-1">About Us
        <ul class="sub-menu" tabindex="-1">
          <li tabindex="-1">
          <p>Meet The Team</p>
          </li>
          <li tabindex="-1">
          <p>Testimonials</p>
          </li>
          <li tabindex="-1">
          <p>Mission and Vision</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menuItem">Resources
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li>
          <p>Big Island Go-Tos</p>
          </li>
          <li>
          <p>Moving To Kona 101</p>
          </li>
          <li>
          <p>Island News</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menuItem">Search MLS
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li>
          <p>Kona Searches</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

$('.menuItem').keydown(function(e){
  if (e.which == 9) {
    $('li.menuItem').focus();
    console.log($('menuItem'));
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`li` elements do not get focus, so what you would do is make the text within an `a` because anchors can get focus. Below would be a way of doing this

```js
$('li>a').keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 9) {
    //Get the submenu
    var subMenu = $(this).next('ul');
    subMenu.addClass('open');
    //Check if you're on the last subchild and close the menu
    if ($(this).parent('li').is(':last-child:not(".menu>li>a")')) {
      $(this).parent('li').parent('.open').removeClass('open')
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.sub-menu {
  display: none;
}
.sub-menu.open {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navigation-container">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li class="menuItem">
        <a href="#">About Us</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li>
          <a href="#">Meet The Team</a>
          </li>
          <li>
          <a href="#">Testimonials</a>
          </li>
          <li>
          <a href="#">Mission and Vision</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menuItem">
      <a href="#">Resources</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li>
          <a href="#">Big Island Go-Tos</a>
          </li>
          <li>
          <a href="#">Moving To Kona 101</a>
          </li>
          <li>
          <a href="#">Island News</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menuItem">
      <a href="#">Search MLS</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li>
          <a href="#">Kona Searches</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: thank you! @Pindo, not only did this work nicely, you gave me a lot to go off of .. thank you thank you .. would you recommend using .hide() once reaching the length of each sub-menu as my next steps? Made my day, thanks again.

Comment: @gmatsushima if you remove the open class it'll hide that particular sub-menu

Comment: struggling with trying to removeClass after a certain length

Comment: I'd like loop to go through each sub-menu, once reached each sub-menu's length, removeClass('open') error - subMenu out of scope or loop not reaching conditional ```$('li > a').keydown(function(e){

  //var sublength = $('ul.sub-menu > li').length;
  var sub1length = $('ul#sub1length > li').length;
  if (e.which == 9) {
    for (var i = 0; i < sub1length; i++){

      if(i < 3){
      var subMenu = $(this).next('ul');
      subMenu.addClass('open');
      }
      else{
        console.log('help');
      }
    }

  }

  //console.log($('ul#sub1length > li').length);
  });```

Comment: @gmatsushima i've edited the answer above to remove the open :)

Comment: wow, thank you .. how does removeClass know not remove 'open' from $(this).parent('li').parent('.open')? And instead, from the previous sub-menu?

Comment: @gmatsushima `$(this)` denotes the current item. so `$(this).parent('li').parent('open')` gets the current item's parent li's parent that has an `open` class